# jzebra.appendHTML from Ajax

Tags: java, jquery, model-view-controller, applet

I use Java applet jzebra. When I get html code form ajax and try print, I get source html but not formating html. 
I try replace not need symbols

```
.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "\n");
```

But not help me

this my code

```
$(".bg-color-blueDark").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).parent().attr("href"),
            success: function (result) {
                d.dialog();
                document.jzebra.findPrinter();
                var test = result.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "\n");
                //document.jzebra.appendHTML("<html><head><meta charset=\"windows-1251\" /><title>Receipt</title><style type=\"text/css\">body{font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;}td{border-bottom:solid 1px #000;}.style1{width: 87px;height: 91px;}</style></head><body><table style=\"width: 300px;\"><tr style=\"display:none\"><td style=\"width:70%\"></td><td style=\"width:30%\"></td></tr><tr><td colspan=\"2\" style=\"text-align:center\" ><img class=\"style1\" src=\"data:image/png;base64,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\" alt=\"\" /></td></tr><tr><td colspan=\"2\" style=\"text-align:center\" ><p style=\"font-size:14px; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;\">Система управления очередью решила одну из важнейших проблем современного мира, в котором нужно успеть сделать тысячи дел и не терять попусту свое время</p></td></tr><tr><td colspan=\"2\" style=\"text-align:center\" ><p style=\"font-size:30px; font-weight:bold; padding:7px 2px 7px 2px;\">QLogic</p></td></tr><tr><td colspan=\"2\" style=\"text-align:center\" ><p style=\"font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic; padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;\">Система управления очередью</p></td></tr><tr><td colspan=\"2\" style=\"text-align:center\" ><p style=\"font-size:65px; font-weight:bold\">A-1234</p></td></tr><tr><td colspan=\"2\" style=\"text-align:center\" ><p style=\"font-size:22px; font-weight:bold;  font-style:italic; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;\">VIP - клиент</p></td></tr><tr><td colspan=\"2\"><ul style=\"font-size:12px; padding:8px 5px 0px 25px\"><li style=\"padding:2px 2px 2px 0px\">Предоставляемая услуга номер 1 Предоставляемая  Предоставляемая </li><li style=\"padding:2px 2px 2px 0px\">Предоставляемая услуга номер 2</li><li style=\"padding:2px 2px 2px 0px\">Предоставляемая услуга номер 3</li><li style=\"padding:2px 2px 2px 0px\">Предоставляемая услуга номер 4</li></ul></td></tr><tr><td><p style=\"font-size:13px; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;\">Время регистрации:</p></td><td><p style=\"font-size:13px; font-weight:bold; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px; text-align:center;\">14:45:06</p></td></tr><tr><td><p style=\"font-size:13px; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;\">Оператор:</p></td><td><p style=\"font-size:13px; font-weight:bold; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px; text-align:center;\">1, 2, 3</p></td></tr><tr><td><p style=\"font-size:13px; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;\">Этаж:</p></td><td><p style=\"font-size:13px; font-weight:bold; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px; text-align:center;\">2</p></td></tr><tr><td><p style=\"font-size:13px; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;\">Людей в очереди:</p></td><td><p style=\"font-size:13px; font-weight:bold; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px; text-align:center;\">21</p></td></tr><tr><td><p style=\"font-size:13px; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;\">Время ожидания:</p></td><td><p style=\"font-size:13px; font-weight:bold; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px; text-align:center;\">14 мин</p></td></tr></table></body></html>");
                document.jzebra.appendHTML(test);
                document.jzebra.printHTML();
                monitorPrinting();
            }
        });
        return false;

    });
```

Comment: Are you sure, that your Zebra Printer supports PostScript? It's needed to print html using jZebra lib.

Comment: if I use write this document.jzebra.appendHTML("<html><body><h1>Hello word</h1></body></html>"); printed fine

Comment: Try to replace: `result.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "");` instead of your replacing.

Comment: Show me then your example test value which cannot be printed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I find problem. If return value starts with space we haved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try for replace your code :

```
var data = data.split(yourText).join(yourReplaceText);
```

and for ajax code you can try with like this :

// PRINT DIRECT TO PRINTER

```
    var applet = document.jzebra;
    applet.findPrinter();
    applet.append(String.fromCharCode(15)); //condensed font

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: Rich.config.yourPathReport + yourUrlReport
        success: function (response) {

            var data = response.responseText;
            var title = "YOUR TEXT";

            var data = data.split(title).join(title2);

            applet.append(data);
            console.info(data);
            applet.print();

        },

        failure: function (response, options) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Failed Print, ' + response.getResponseHeader("Error Msg"));
        }
    });
```